# Validation for dynamically generated reference Template Driven Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am creating a dynamic form, I am going through my own way through template driven, I don't want to create with the reactive approach. Everything is working fine but only validations are creating a problem for me. I have uploaded a small piece of code of my project

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let a of UserFormArray; let i = index">
   <form #f="ngForm" name="FormName">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let ab of a; let i2 = index">
      <ng-container *ngIf="ab.type === 'text'">
        <input type={{ab.type}} pInputText name={{ab.name}} ngModel 
                                     #{{ab.name}}="ngModel" required>
           <ng-container *ngIf="ab.name.errors?.required">
                    <div>
                        Input Error
                    </div>
           </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </form>
 <p-button label="Click" (onClick)="sender(f)"></p-button>
</ng-container>
```

The problem is that I am not able to put validation here, I am using the template-driven approach and I don't want to go for reactive form so please don't suggest the reactive link, it's my requirement to go with template driven, I know I am missing the small thing. But not able to figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create template reference variable dynamically but you should know that this variable is unique within embedded view.

So propably you're looking for the following:

```
<input ... #ngModel="ngModel" required>
    <ng-container *ngIf="ngModel.errors?.required">
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/V37RnP3yjzutRuIc126Q)**

Comment: ngModel.errors? is this ngModel reference name or normal ngModel

Comment: It's just template reference name. You can also do `<input ... #blabla="ngModel" required>
    <ng-container *ngIf="blabla.errors?.required">`

Comment: I just forgotten that reference is used just for checking things on that element so creating dynamically reference doesn't make sense